# Работа с массивом

Tags: алгоритм, php

Приветствую всех, кто зашел.

Охота создать массив с числами типа (2,3,5,7,11,13...); массив создавать умею, но нужен массив с большим количеством значений; вопрос, как его написать, чтобы он был максимально коротким?

Массив будет пополняться, далее методом перебора пробовать определенную переменную делить на каждое значение из массива. Собственно в моей прошлой теме была такая конструкция:

```
while ($d001=mysql_fetch_assoc($q001)){extract($d001);if($i001<1){$x001=$n001/$d001['id'];$t001=$x001-$d001['id'];if($t001>=0){$re001=$n001%$d001['id'];if($re001==0){$i001=$i001+1;};};};}
```

Перебор на множители из таблицы. Вот хочу узнать, а можно ли перебор делать по заранее сделанному массиву?

Comment: php это не наилучший выбор для решения данной задачи.

Почитайте про Решето Эратосфена. 

Comment: Это не весь код, и решение Решето Эратосфена применяется в нем успешно. Да и вопрос не по оптимизации, а про массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите цикл, который перебиал бы элементы массива.
Это либо

```
$arr = array(,,,,,,);
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
 //$arr[$i] - текущий элемент массива
}
```

Либо, если ключи произвольные

```
foreach($arr as $arr_key=>$arr_value){
 //$arr_value - копия текущего элемента
 //$arr_key - ключ текущего элемента 
 //$arr[$arr_key] - текущий элемент 
}
```

Comment: for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){  
заменить на  
    for($i=0, $c=count($arr); $i<$c;$i++){  
для больших проектов ускорит работу в разы =)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по значениям, нужны именно простые числа. Тогда и правда Решето Эрастофена. Если хочется создать просто большой массив, используйте [мануалы](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)